# Apache Velocity not loading CSS

Tags: java, spring, velocity

Am using Apache velocity template and spring to send an email notification.
Trying to load fontawesome css below is my the snippet but this is not loading the fontawesome icons.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:#CAE7EA;padding:0.5%;"><span style="color:red;"><b><i class="fa fa-server" style="color:blue;margin- right:1%;">Testing</i></div> </body>    </html>
```

Am tring below example

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-compose-html-emails-in-java-with-spring-and-velocity/

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Velocity has no notion of HTML or CSS, it renders your template. The client loading your email/HTML has to fetch resources.

Comment: Am not able to find this css link in the sent mail source

Comment: Share sample code and the template.

Comment: Updated the code.
for your info am able to send the mails but there's no fontawesome icon in the mail